# Parse age integer to date with moment.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, momentjs

i'm trying to query mongoose by age range, i don't have `age` on my schema, but a `dob`.
what i'm trying to achieve is:
convert `age integer` to a date (to essentailly return the birthdate).

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Knowing someone's age can only give us a bound on their birthdate, for example if someone is 30 at June 1 2018, they were either born in early 1988 or late 1987.
We know their *latest* birthdate will be June 1 1988. We also know their earliest birthdate will be June 2 1987.

Moment.js gives us some nice methods to calculate dates based on time differences.

For example:

```
var ageYears = 30;
var latestBirthdate = new moment().add(moment.duration(-ageYears, 'years')).startOf('day');
var earliestBirthdate = new moment().add(moment.duration(-(ageYears + 1), 'years')).add(moment.duration(1, 'days')).startOf('day');

var ageRange = earliestBirthdate.format("DD MMM, YYYY") + ' to ' + latestBirthdate.format("DD MMM, YYYY");

console.log(ageRange);
```

What is less ambiguous is calculating someone's age based on their DOB. So we can can at a given point in time say who is over or under a given threshold age.

We can query using earliestBirthdate and latestBirthdate and say anyone born within this range matches the age.

JSFiddle is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/hLypn9s1/22/